# What do I change in my VIM config to do this? (remove the arrows)

Tags: linux, unix, vim

My files have this "invisible arrows"
How do I disable this completely?

> --->--->--->---

This is my vim config. What do I have to change to do this?

```
set nohlsearch
set ai
set bg=dark
set showmatch
highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=DarkGray
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~
set list
autocmd BufRead *.py set smartindent cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set smartindent
syntax on
set listchars=tab:>-
set listchars+=trail:.
set ignorecase
set smartcase
map <C-t><up> :tabr<cr>
map <C-t><down> :tabl<cr>
map <C-t><left> :tabp<cr>
map <C-t><right> :tabn<cr>
filetype indent on
filetype on
filetype plugin on
set pastetoggle=<F5>
imap <C-Right> <End>
imap <C-Left> <Home>
imap <C-Down> <PageDown>
imap <C-Up> <PageUp>

nmap <C-Right> <End>
nmap <C-Left> <Home>
nmap <C-Down> <PageDown>
nmap <C-Up> <PageUp>
```

Comment: I'm curious as to how this invisible arrows look like. Can you posy a screenshot? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The red arrows are a combination of these lines:

```
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~
set list
```

The red arrows are your tab characters in the file being displayed when `tab:>-` for `listchars` and the `list` setting is on.

The simplest way to get rid of the red arrows is to change

```
set list
```

to

```
set nolist
```

Also try:

```
:help listchars
```

for info

Comment: Or ":set list!" to toggle. I have that on a keyboard shortcut. Very handy to check formatting before check-in/etc.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the [`listchars` settings](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'listchars'). Or just get rid of `set list`.

You can also toggle this from the command line. From normal mode:

```
:set list!
```

...will toggle list mode ([source](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/46405)).